# How do I locate a mouse click in a canvas while in a table?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have built a control to select colors from a color wheel with independent sliders for hue saturation and brightness.  I want to use two of them side by side, the formatting leads me to want to put these canvas objects in a table.  Now, when I to localize the clicks, the canvas offset values (`canvas.offsetLeft` and `canvas.offsetTop` are not 0 so the clicks are located far to far to the right and bottom from where they are).  Has anyone figured out how to localize a mouse click from a canvas while in a TABLE.  It works fine otherwise.

Sorry to bother you, I have figured an answer by passing the offsets from the table objects to the object handling the mouse events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the desired canvas element:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
```

And then use `getBoundingClientRect` to give you the left and top coordinates of the canvas

```
var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetX=BB.left;
var offsetY=BB.top;
```